# Heroku gets stuck installing Gemfile dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

When I try to deploy to heroku the gems never finished installing. I did a bundle update on my local machine to see if there was a problem. That did not help.

I suspect it might be libv8, but that should not be deployed because of the following in my config/application.rb file:

```
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
```

Here is the log when I deploy my rails app to heroku:

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 176, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (156/156), done.
Writing objects: 100% (176/176), 37.46 KiB, done.
Total 176 (delta 41), reused 0 (delta 0)
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.0.pre.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs bin/ --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Installing rake (10.0.3)
       Installing i18n (0.6.1)           
       Installing multi_json (1.5.0)
       Installing activesupport (3.2.9)           
       Installing builder (3.0.4)
       Installing activemodel (3.2.9)           
       Installing erubis (2.7.0)
       Installing journey (1.0.4)           
       Installing rack (1.4.1)
       Installing rack-cache (1.2)           
       Installing rack-test (0.6.2)
       Installing hike (1.2.1)           
       Installing tilt (1.3.3)
       Installing sprockets (2.2.2)
       Installing actionpack (3.2.9)
       Installing mime-types (1.19)
       Installing polyglot (0.3.3)
       Installing treetop (1.4.12)
       Installing mail (2.4.4)
       Installing actionmailer (3.2.9)
       Installing arel (3.0.2)
       Installing tzinfo (0.3.35)
       Installing activerecord (3.2.9)
       Installing activeresource (3.2.9)
       Installing bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
       Installing sass (3.2.5)
       Installing bootstrap-sass (2.2.2.0)
       Installing coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
       Installing execjs (1.4.0)
       Installing coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Installing rack-ssl (1.3.2)
       Installing json (1.7.6)
       Installing rdoc (3.12)
       Installing thor (0.16.0)
       Installing railties (3.2.9)
       Installing coffee-rails (3.2.2)
       Installing jquery-rails (2.1.4)
```

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.9'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'json'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.2.2.0'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  gem 'libv8'
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug'
```

Answer (score 1):

It was installing libv8. When I first started I needed that to get around some error. Now it seems I do not need it.